# Give full access to user in one Domain to another Domain

Tags: dns, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-domain

**What i have**

I created 2 way trust in both  forest and then wide authentication between them with conditional forwarders  in DNS in both domain i dint create any stub zone or secondary zone since i read the conditional forwards are enough both domain controllers are 2012 r2

**What i want to Do**

I d'like to give delagatation contorll to admins from one forest to the other
the way i saw *it can happend is like this Add the Domain Admins@OneForest group to the Builtin\Adminstrators@OtherForest group.
This effectively grants user-level privileges on OtherForest domain computers, and administrative privileges on the domain controllers for OtherForest.*
and latter assign remote desktop access to all users both ways

**The problem**

Although the trust is validate it seems i cant see any user or group from both domain even when i try to search for the group form one domain to the other it seems like it inst there

Comment: Not sure, but seems that the only solution would  be the creation of an additional forest since, multiple forests would be capable of providing administrative autonomy, isolation as well as configuration of directory partitions, separate security boundaries, and the flexibility to use an independent namespaces for each forest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer  the solutions was the trust between forest was damaged and need it to be repair  with validation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer the solutions was the trust between forest was damaged and need it to be repair with validation in the in going trust